# Load js file into typescript file

Tags: typescript

I have a simple TypeScript (ts) which needs a function from a JavaScript file. How can I import that js file into ts file? Do I have to create a ts file for that js file to be able to use it in my ts file?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The easiest way is to just `declare` the function you're using:

**File1.js**

```
function greet() { return "Hello!"; }
```

**File2.ts**

```
declare function greet(): string;

/* ... later ... */
var hi = greet();
```

---

If your scenario is more complex (i.e. multiple files referencing File1.js, or there are many functions in File1.js that would clutter up File2.ts), you can make a File1.d.ts file and reference that from File2.ts:

**File1.d.ts**

```
function greet(): string;
```

**File2.ts**

```
/// <reference path="File1.d.ts" />

/* ... later ... */
var hi = greet();
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thank you this works! One file I use however has methods added to Math library. So Math.uuid.js file has three methods in it; Math.uuid() returns string, and other two... TS complains to this "declare function Math.uuid(): string;" (obviously). How would I bring these methods in? Thanks!

Comment: Found it! I declared this interface...
interface Math {
    uuid(): string;
}
and it's all good.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically generate a *.d.ts file from the .js file? Thanks - dave

Comment: @DavidThielen some good explanations of why that's not easy to do here https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/451987. i'm sure there's much more written on the subject but this satisfied my questions

Answer (score 2):

Just for the archives,if you add a /// ref for a JavaScript file inside your TS file, the compiler will try to validate all the code in the JS files and throw a huge error list.  Try it with jQuery or something like that and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Yup, I have seen that. I put declare var $ and not include that ref in projects which don't have jquery the d.ts file.

Comment: That's the quickest way to add support for any type that you don't have a .d.ts file for.  The nice thing about the definition files is you get Intellisense.

Comment: I use DefinitelyTyped files all the time, that's a great project.

Comment: it doesn't even let you do this (i'm not sure if this changed since 2012) - you get `Incorrect reference: Only files with a .ts extension are allowed` - or maybe you meant to rename the .js to .ts. either way you're certainly right that you get a big mess :-)