# How to Call a javascript method from TypeScript class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to call a Javascript method from a TypeScript class. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753311/load-js-file-into-typescript-file), but it did not work for me. I am getting the error

> Uncaught Referenceerror : greet is not defined

Here is my code:

```
//Resources.js
function greet() {return "Hello";}

//Modifiers.ts
 declare function greet(): string;
  var hi = greet();
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure your `Resources.js` file is loaded before `Modifiers.js` runs. This runtime error is normally caused by not adding the dependent script to the web page.

You should have both of these...

```
<script src="Resources.js"></script>
<script src="Modifiers.js"></script>
```