# Trouble instantiating an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

This should all work, but doesn't. I have the following typescript code:

```
module LayoutEngine {
    class WorkerApi {
        private worker : Worker;

        constructor() {
            debugger;
            this.worker = new Worker("layout-worker.js");
        }
```

And I am trying to create this object in javascript:

```
require(["../common/events", "worker-api.js"], function (events) {
    var api = new LayoutEngine.WorkerApi();
```

But I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` and in the debugger `LayoutEngine does evaluate as an object but LayoutEngine.WorkerApi resolves as undefined`.

**What am I missing in my declaration to create it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you exporting the classes correctly?

I think you need to "export" the class WorkerApi

So your code should be

```
module LayoutEngine {
    export class WorkerApi {
        private worker : Worker;

        constructor() {
            debugger;
            this.worker = new Worker("layout-worker.js");
        }
```

And then, import them like this

```
var workerApi = require(["../common/events", "worker-api.js"];
var api = new workerApi();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried that - and then LayoutEngine is undefined also. So even worse.

Comment: Did you reference the files at the top? Something like this--          /// <reference path="../common/events/worker-api.ts"/>

Comment: No but reference is a .ts construct, I'm having the problem in the .js file.

Comment: Also, you mentioned that you are using typescript but you have '.js' instead of '.ts' in your reference. I am confused :P

Comment: Aahh.. Got ya.. I think ..  See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753311/load-js-file-into-typescript-file

Comment: No, my problem is the other direction. That's call a javascript object in a typescript file. I need to instantiate a typescript class in a javascript file.

Comment: Ohh, in that case, the only thing i can think of is you should change this line --  class WorkerApi { to this -- export class WorkerApi { ...... i.e. Add export keyword infront of your WorkerApi class, and then it should not give the undefined error. Do not export the module, just the class!

Comment: That was it! I'll mark this as the solution but can you update your answer? Thank You!