# Import JavaScript object from external file in Angular2 Component

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger-ui

I am trying to use SwaggerUI in an angular2 project with TypeScript. SwaggerUI doesn't see to have TypeScript definitions.So I am trying to use the JavaScript file.

This project is created using ASP.Net Core SPA Services template. I have added all the SwaggerUI files from "dist" folder to "wwwroot" folder in my project.

I have referenced the JavaScript file of SwaggerUI from the "wwwroot" folder of my project in the _Layout.cshtml (view page) just like normal javascript file and trying to use ShaggerUIBundle object.

_Layout.cshtml

```
<script src="/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js"> </script>
<script src="/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"> </script>
```

Swagger.Component.ts

```
//my import statements

export class SwaggerComponent implements OnInit {
    SwaggerUIBundle:any;
}
```

Now SwaggerUIBundle is populated with the object that I am expecting. But I am not able to use this anywhere in the component.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 (<any>window).ui = this.SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "<url>",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    presets: [
        this.SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis
    ],
    plugins: [
        this.SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  })
}
```

> this.SwaggerUIBundle is always null.

I think this is because of the fact that no value is actually assigned to SwaggerUIBundle, though it has populated with an object.

SwaggerUIBundle is a function. I tried multiple ways to assign this function as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753311/load-js-file-into-typescript-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42478930/how-to-import-javascript-file-into-angular2).

I tried to import instead of referencing the file.

```
import SwaggerUIBundle from 'path from root of the app'
```

As the "wwwroot" folder is a virtual folder, that represents root folder of the application, when I try to import using "import" TypeScript compiler throws an error that it can't find the file.

Then I moved all SwaggerUI related files to the respective angular component folder and tried importing from there. Then I get this error.

> 'allowJs is not set.

I have added 'allowJs' to tsconfig. Still the error wont go away.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": [ "node" ],
    "allowJs": true
  }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where did you import SwaggerUI js files?

Comment: Why would it be available on `this`?

Comment: `(<any>window).ui = this.SwaggerUIBundle({` does not make any sense.

Comment: SwaggerUI requires the ui object ti be present on window. So I am trying to get it. But this.SwaggerUIBundle is null so it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Hi @user3731783, did you ever get this to work? I'm following a very similar path as you, and am having trouble getting the TypeScript to play nicely with the JavaScript with the SwaggerUIBundle.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to an instance of the enclosing class, not the lexical environment of the module that defines the class.

Instead of using `this` import and refer to `SwaggerUIBundle` directly as in

```
import SwaggerUIBundle from 'path/to/swagger-ui/dist/bundle.js';
```

Additionally, instead of initializing it in `ngOnInit`, a per component lifecycle event, you likely want to do it once

```
import SwaggerUIBundle from 'path/to/swagger-ui/dist/bundle.js';

SwaggerUIBundle({
  url: "<url>",
  dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
  presets: [
    SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis
  ],
  plugins: [
    SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
  ],
  layout: "StandaloneLayout"
});
```

This sort of logic should be extracted into a dedicated function or a service in order to keep your views clean.

Comment: I have edited my question to add more information about my project setup and answer to your question in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below method to include the javascript file,

component.ts

```js
@Component({
selector: 'test',
template: `
    <div class="row">
      Loading...
    </div>
    `,
styles: []
})
export class TestComponent {

public ngOnInit() {
    // Pass js file path
    this.loadScript('src/assets/js/myCropper.js');       
}

public loadScript(url) {
    console.log('preparing to load...')
    let js = document.createElement('script');
    js.src = url;
    js.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
 }
}
```